# error with plotting keras NN (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im getting the errors below when trying to run the code in this tutorial [tutorial](https://github.com/llSourcell/ethereum_future/blob/master/A%20Deep%20Learning%20Approach%20to%20Predicting%20Cryptocurrency%20Prices.ipynb/). I was able to fix the previous errors but im getting stuck at this point since the training for this network takes like 10 minutes.

When i go to line 254 its just a commented out line with no code and I cant see anything wrong with the plt.show command. I cant find the return statement it says is at line 254 in the code so im not sure what the issue is. Can anyone see what it is ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 52, in run_file pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
line 18, in execfile exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
line 369, in <module> plt.show(fig1)
line 254, in show return _show(*args, **kw)

TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you refer to the line in the tutorial which is `plt.show(fig1)`. This is simply wrong.

You can either call `plt.show()` to show all plots present in the pyplot state.

Or you can call `fig1.show()` if there is a figure `fig1`, but this would probably not work in a jupyter notebook.

In a Jupyter notebook you can instead simply state the name of the figure to show it,

```
fig1
```

Comment: This isnt being run in a jupyter notebook. Im running it in pycharm IDE
These are the previous line

# Testing the Model
y_predict, real_y_test, real_y_predict, fig1 = test_model(model, X_test, Y_test, unnormalized_bases)

#Show the plot
plt.show(fig1)

Comment: That's fine, I gave you all the options you have, in or outside a jupyter notebook.

Comment: thanks fig1.show() worked